# Como setar o id= com ' em vez de "

Tags: javascript, c#, html, cefsharp

Como posso setar o id= com ' em vez de " pois se eu tento executar o script no chromeBrowser.ExecuteScriptAsync com o id="" ele da erro, como posso fazer isso?

Código html/javascript

```
var x = '<label id="idteste">Testando' +
        '</label></div>'
$('#labelhm p:first').html(x);
```

O problema está no id="idteste" que tem o "" e quando se coloca no c# da erro.

Já tentei "+"idteste"+" que tira o erro, mas ai da erro no script dizendo que o id não é válido

O script é muito grande e tem vários {} então não consigo fazer isso:

```
Exemplo:

chromeBrowser.ExecuteScriptAsync("id={}", "idteste");
```

Nem isso:

```
chromeBrowser.ExecuteScriptAsync($"id={idteste}");
```

Preciso que fique assim: 'idteste', alguém sabe alguma solução? Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inverter os apóstrofe por aspas e vice-versa da certo, mas você usar um *escape* \ do javascript

```js
  var x = '<label id=\'idteste\'>Testando' +
      '</label></div>'
  $('#labelhm p:first').html(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

Só alterando a ordem das quotes funciona. Se foi isso que entendi e precisa que o id esteja no formato id='teste'

```js
  var x = "<label id='idteste'>Testando" +
      "</label></div>"
  $('#labelhm p:first').html(x);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="labelhm">
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/h79whqu8/1/

Comment: Consegui, é que oque executa o script aqui não aceita o '', dai fiz uma gambiarra e funcionou, mas valeu.

Comment: Ah entendi, que bom que deu certo. Se puder compartilha conosco ai a sua solução.